# Is it possible to change the type of an array in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [byte array to Int Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437203/byte-array-to-int-array)

I have a large array of bytes, can I somehow interpret it as an array of ints, such that each entry is just four of the original bytes?

I mean something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i += 4) {
    intArray[i / 4] = byteArray[i] << 24 + byteArray[i+1] << 16 + byteArray[i+2] << 8 + byteArray[i+3];
}
```

but rather than copying the whole array byte by byte which takes forever because the array is huge, just read ints off the array that already exists.

Comment: You can surely read off bytes and put them in int variables and they'll automatically be up-converted to ints. The bytes in the array itself however will and must remain bytes.

Comment: `ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray).toIntBuffer()`

Comment: Oh yes, that works. Sorry about the duplicate, I read that question before but didn't know what a bytebuffer was an assumned it would involve duplicating the array.

Comment: @user1559670 - it *does* involve "duplicating the array".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this code:

```
IntBuffer intarray = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytearray).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer();
 intarray.get(100);
```

will take very few extra heap space. Actually, it wraps byte array and creates a int array view. Significantly faster, in my PC for buffer size of INT_MAX takes few nanoseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is it possible to change the type of an array in Java?

A: In general, "no".  You'd have to copy/convert item by item.

In this specific case: yes, certainly.  Just use asIntBuffer().  For example:

```
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class MyClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    IntBuffer IntBuf = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
    IntBuf.put(array);
    ...
```

Note that these conversions (and related "flip", "wrap", ability to change byte order, etc) were introduced with [java.nio](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html).

Comment: PS: Bohemian is correct.  The *original* array is unchanged.  asIntBuffer() and friends just *copies* the array.  Transforming as needed.  Very, very efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

No. The type of an array is invariant.

No if's, but's or maybe's.

Comment: You're absolutely correct :)  I think the OP just wanted to know if there was an alternative to copying and converting the array element-by-element.  And, in this case, there is.