# How to shift bits across array of ints

Tags: java, int, bit-manipulation, shift, sha256

Alright, I'll keep this plain & simple.

I'm working on a brute implementation of SHA-256 in Java, and to keep the class methods conducive to other classes in the app, I've decided to I/O the data as an array of 32-bit integers (int). Obviously, these kinds of uses rely heavily on use of bitwise operators, so how do I accomplish bitwise shifting *across* an array of ints, as such:

Given an array of data, suppose:

```
 int[16] data;
```

where the first 14 integers' worth of data is filled with 0x0000000, for the purposes of conversation, but the lowest two are filled respectively:

```
 data[14] = 0x12345678;
 data[15] = 0x01ABCDEF;
```

How do I accomplish a leftwise shift so that if shifted left by two,

```
 data[13] = 0x00000012;
 data[14] = 0x34567801;
 data[15] = 0xABCDEF00;
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: When you shift, also OR in the correct bits from the next int. For example, `data[15] = (data[15] << 2) | (data[14] >>> 30)`

Comment: Perhaps use a BigInteger and create an API "to keep the class methods conducive to other classes in the app". BigInteger has methods like `shiftLeft(int n)` see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: @RonE - Is it possible to construct a `BigInteger` instance from a int array? The Oracle literature only supplies examples using a byte array. Does the 32- versus 8-bit nature make a difference during construction?

Comment: @blasthash If you receive your data as an int[16] then write a method that converts it to a byte[64]

Comment: Or just shift them like I said. It's not hard.

Comment: OP didn't say it was a circular shift. Even if it is, it's still trivial.

Comment: Yes, obviously everyone knows everything about SHA-256. Anyway, you only need to save data[15], not the entire thing.

Comment: @RonE well ok. But are you sure it's true? OP said in a comment that it's for the padding stage, and I don't really see why that should be a circular shift. The rest of the algorithm has rotations, but they're on 32bit integers.

Comment: @harold I think you're right, OP should explain the usage more clearly in the question.

Comment: You can convert the int array to bytes with `ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length * 4); buffer.asIntBuffer().put(data); byte[] bytes = buffer.array();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Write a helper method to convert your `int[16] data` to `byte[64] bytedata`.

2) Create a BigInteger using the constructor `BigInteger(byte[] val)`

3) Bitshift using `shiftLeft(int n)` and `shiftRight(int n)`

4) Write a helper method to convert your `byte[64] bytedata` back to `int[16] data`. See [byte array to Int Array here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437203/byte-array-to-int-array)

Other useful methods in BigInteger include `clearBit(int n)`, `setBit(int n)`, `flipBit(int n)`, and `testBit(int n)`

Answer (score -1):

For bitwise shift left:

```
`x << n` is the same as `x *= 2^n`
```

To see the overflowing bit (MSB):
    `x / (2^32) >= 1` //Since we are using an 32 bit int

---

Likewise, for bitwise shift right:

```
`x >> n` is the same as `x /= 2^n`
```

To see the overflowing bit (LSB):
    `x % 2`

Append the overflowing bit to the adjacent int by adding or subtracting set values. You should really use a BigInteger like I mentioned in my comment, anything else will require an implementation where you read and append the bits moving between array locations yourself.

Comment: Is it possible to 'downconvert' back to a int array from BigInteger? If you've read the algo, the stage I'm implementing is the _padding_ stage, where an arbitrary number of bits are appended to the end of the value to establish the number at 512-bit. Most of the other processing in the algorithm though, is by _direct_ relation of specific 32-bit segments in the array to constants or functions, so I'd prefer to be able to retain the ease of that capacity.

Comment: I could do it by shifting right 32, then back 32 to get 32 bits truncated and divide, but that's a roundabout and inefficient method.

Comment: @blasthash Yes, use `toByteArray()` and write a helper function to convert to an int array. Java is about layers and chaining, use modular pieces to achieve your goal.