# ByteBuffer to int array (each byte)

Tags: java, arrays

Related to question [byte array to Int Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437203/byte-array-to-int-array), however I would like to convert each byte to an int, not each 4-bytes.

Is there a better/cleaner way than this:

```
protected static int[] bufferToIntArray(ByteBuffer buffer) {
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
    buffer.get(byteArray);

    int[] intArray = new int[byteArray.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
        intArray[i] = byteArray[i];
    }

    return intArray;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably prefer

```
int[] array = new int[buffer.capacity()];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = buffer.get(i);
}
return array;
```

Answer (score 0):

for kotlin programmers..

```
fun getIntArray(byteBuffer: ByteBuffer): IntArray{
    val array = IntArray(byteBuffer.capacity())
    for (i in array.indices) {
        array[i] = byteBuffer.getInt(i)
    }
    return array
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This produces an int array:

`int[] intArray = byteBuffer.asInBuffer().array()`

Comment: It won't work for JDK though, it will throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. `asIntBuffer()` creates a **view**, but `array()` requires something that is backed by an accessible array to work. However, this method works on Android.